# ffmpeg fails to capture video running on screen

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to capture a slide presentation as video. I'm using the following command to capture my screen

```
ffmpeg \
   -f x11grab -s 1024x768 -r 25 -i $DISPLAY \
   -f alsa -i pulse \
   -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -vb 1000k \
   -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k \
   test.avi
```

This works (application windows on the screen are visible and sound is recorded in test.avi), but the problem is: Any video shown on the screen (e.g. a youtube video running in a browser window, but also e.g. a video played by mplayer) only appears as an empty (e.g. green) box when I play the captured video (test.avi).

I'm using ffmpeg version 0.8.16-4:0.8.16-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS with the nvidia-331 driver (effect is the same with older nvidia-304).

I would really appreciate any suggestions, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Disable video acceleration for the video player. Currently the video is being overlaid by the video hardware and not drawn using software so it can't be captured by simply taking screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentelly stumbled over the solution to the problem, even though I don't get it. It seems to depend on the window manager you are using. I either use "Gnome Classic" or "Gnome Classic (no effects)" (selected in the login frame).

Capturing videos running on the screen fails with the "no effects" version (you see a blank box in the recording), but it works fine (without any changes to either the player or ffmpeg) under the other one.

This solves my problem, but I would be curious how the window manager affects the capture problem. I learned that "Gnome Classic (no effects)" uses Metacity, whereas "Gnome Classic" uses Compiz (see http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GNOME3_Fallback-Modus, in German).

I think njahnke is right that is has something to do with hardware acceleration (thanks for the answer), but the relation to the window manager is not clear.

Maybe it's useful to know for somebody encountering the same problem.

[Edit] I just learned the following from a colleague (I'm citing and translating): "[The relation to the window manager] is obvious. In "Gnome Classic (no effects)" the so-called "compositing" is switched off, i.e. the individual windows draw directly into buffers which are completely managed and visualized by the graphics card (which prevents that the window manager has access to the window content). With "compositing", the windows are drawn into buffers (to which the software may add effects) and only afterwards transferred to the frame buffer. The graphics card then just visualizes the final frame buffer, not the individual windows. This frame buffer can therefore also be accessed by ffmpeg."